# Custom SELECT for findBy in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I intend to build multilingual website. So I have DB table with columns:

- id
- text_en
- text_pl

When getting data from DB I'd like to have only `id` and `text` fields. Normally, I'd issue:

```
SELECT id, text_$locale AS text FROM page ...
```

How to do it in Doctrine so that I have such SELECT done automatically when I use `findBy()` or `findOneBy()`? Is Query Builder my only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a query is the semantic option; you should put it in as a custom method in a repository.

I'm posting an example here so that I can use it for reference later on.

Quick example:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * PageRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class PageRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    /**
     * Gets and id and page name based by ID
     * @return array
     */
    public function findNameById($id)
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
                      ->createQuery("SELECT p.id, p.name
                                     FROM Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Page p
                                     WHERE p.id = :pageId");
        $query->setParameter('pageId', $id);
        $result = $query->getOneOrNullResult();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you'll have to use a querybuilder or native query if you want to select specific columns.

Specifying individual columns using `findBy` is not possible. You could lazy-load associations to entities in other tables but at a minimum `findBy` will return all columns from the entity's table.